# Check if current user has a post and that post has any term/s from a specific custom taxonomy outside the loop

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, users, terms

I'm looking for a way to check if (whilst outside the loop) the current user..
1. is logged in
2. has a post published
3. their post has any term/terms from a custom taxonomy

I have this so far...

```
<?php if (( 1 == count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "post" ) && is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
blah blah
<?php } ?>
```

I'm just wildly guessing here but could I use `if( has_term( '', 'custom-taxonomy' ) )`? but that's for use inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using WP_Query using author and tax_query.

Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom-taxonomy',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then check if posts are returned through this query.

Please note that this code is not tried or tested and may contain syntax errors.

Comment: How does this work outside the loop? and how does it fit within my conditional?

Comment: The query will return all the posts whose author is current user and those are tagged to any of the custom taxonomy. So if query is empty, no posts satisfying condition. Otherwise it satisfy your condition. And since it is a separate query, it does not need to be in `the loop`.

Comment: Yep, sorry I get it now.

Comment: This worked, thanks... 

`<?php 
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'day_time',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
);
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
?>

<?php // The Loop
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
  $query2->the_post(); ?>

 
 
Well done  
  
  
<?php } } else { ?>
You need to update your availability
<?php } ?>
<?php // Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
`